# Database timeout

Tags: c#, sql, database

I have a program that access database and excecute different methods that have a database call.
I have used one conenction for everything but it caused a timeout while executing a long task:
I basically had to go through the more than 6000 records and execute a stored procedure. I thing that caused a timeout since I used only one database connection for everything.

Then I changed the code, so I open and closing the connection for every method I call with "using" approach.

How should I handle the method that will be called a lot. Shouls I open/close connection everytime I access that method?

Or there is a different approach to it?

I do something like this:

```
foreach(record in MyCollection)//6000
{
    using(connection = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        singledata = GetSingleData(record);
    }
}
```

Here is a GetSingleData()

```
private byte[] GetSingleData(MyObject Data)
{
      byte[] singleData = null;

      using(SqlCommans......)
      {
            try
            {
                 .......
                 //executing stored proc to get just a single row
                 reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                 while(reader.Read())
                 {
                     singleData = (byte[])reader["ColumnName"];
                 }                
            }
            catch(SqlException ex)
            {
                  if(!reader.isClosed)
                      reader.Close();
            }
      }
      return singleData;
}
```

Is it efficient or I can set up some kind of counter and for each 500 records I can check if connection is closed and if it is then reopen it.

Thank's

Comment: Are you still getting the timeout issue? It's a little confusing as to whether or not the problem persisted after the refactoring. BTW, you're using the right approach now (no pun intended).

Comment: The connection pool will handle resource allocation very efficiently.  You should only open the connection specifically where it's being used and close it immediately when you're done.  (That is, wrap it in a `using` block and have as little code as possible within that block.)

Comment: can you post your code? definitely using the same connection and not closing or having your sqlconnection object come out of scope and be garbage collected is not ideal, I myself create a clsSqlClient and its always connected once until I close it.

Comment: I do not get timeouts on a developemt environment, only on production. That's why I did ot get it when testing the code

Answer (score 0):

Try using a persistent connection. Here's a post that might help if you want to try to tune your system (for MySQL):
   http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/04/19/mysql-connection-timeouts/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a thing as **the only good way** to do something. It all depends. In cases where agility is a must and you need to create ad-hoc solutions, opening and closing a connection in each method call might not be good theoretically, but accepted practically.

I urge you to read about these terms and concepts:

1. [Connection pooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool)
2. [Bulk operations (bulk update, bulk insert)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)

They might help you in getting more performance.